# How can I add my local folder with envs to conda path?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, miniconda

I have a folder with multiple envs which I created using conda.
Now when I type `conda info --envs` I want to see my envs in the list as well.

How can I add my envs folder to the paths where conda is searching to collect the envs?

Comment: Alternatively to using `envs_dirs`(as per duplicate), Conda also maintains a registry of the path-based environments that have been activated on the system. See `~/.conda/environments.txt`.